# how to import module only once in python behave step files

Tags: python, import, python-behave

I am very new to Python and Behave. In my step file, `test_steps.py`, I have imported the following:

```
from behave import given, when, then, step
from behave_http.steps import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pdb
import xmltodict
import requests
```

If I created another step file, `test2_steps.py`, I had to import above again. 
Is there a way to avoid that?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, you have to import anything you want to use in a file.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally useful to know all the imports for a given file; however, you can do something like the following:

config.py

```
from behave import given, when, then, step
from behave_http.steps import *
from datetime import datetime
import time
import pdb
import xmltodict
import requests
```

test2_steps.py

```
from config import *
#other code here
```